# Need to remove empty space <p> Tag

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to remove the empty space <p> element using XSL:

XML I'm having:

```
    <Body>
      <p> </p>
      <h1>AAA</h1>
      <p>aaa</p>
    </Body>
```

XSL I Used:

```
   <xsl:strip-space elements="p"/>

   <xsl:template match="Body">
      <xsl:copy>
         <h1><xsl:value-of select="h1[normalize-space()]" separator=" "/></h1>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="h1"/>

   <xsl:template match="p[not(normalize-space())]"/>
```

Output I'm getting like:

```
    <Body>
      <h1>AAA</h1>
      <p> </p>
      <p>aaa</p>
    </Body>
```

Expected output be like:

```
    <Body>
      <h1>AAA</h1>
      <p>aaa</p>
    </Body>
```

I Need to remove the empty space para tags. Please suggest code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != ''">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I do not have an editor now but I tried it online and it gave the output you post as expected "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Body><h1>AAA</h1><p>aaa</p></Body>"

Comment: That empty space <p> element not removing while conversion!!

Comment: Please check what you posted as the output expected, you removed the <p> </p> (element that contained only spaces.

Comment: Sorry @Carlos. Now its working fine. actually that <p> space i gave manually at here. Thats the problem. Now your code is working fine. Thanks a lot